# Selenium works in chrome normally but does not work with chrome headless

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a simple test created from selenium IDE and I have saved it as a **.side** file

In my cmd i execute the command: `selenium-side-runner C:\path\to\file\prueba2.side` and the test is successful.

But when I run the test with chrome headless with the command: `selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[headless]" C:\path\to\file\prueba2.side` it throws the following error:

> TimeoutError: Waiting for element to be located By (css selector, div:
>   nth-child (2)> .rc .LC20lb) Wait timed out after 15163ms

I tried to solve the problem by adding a pause of 5 seconds before the line that generated the problem is executed but it did not work, throws the same problem.

Comment: Since you are seeing a `TimeoutError` on an element locator, can you confirm -- are there any statements searching for elements before the one throwing the error that are working? Or do they all fail? You might need to add more `chromeOptions` to get headless working properly.

Comment: @Christine the statement that generates the error is as follows: `css=div:nth-child(2) > .rc .LC20lb` . What other options might I need to add?

Comment: Do any other findElement calls before that work though? I am trying to figure out if the entire page is breaking, or if there is something wrong with this line in particular.

Comment: No, just look for that item

Answer (score 1):

In the following link I found the solution: https://medium.com/@griggheo/running-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-firefox-headless-mode-on-ubuntu-d32500bb6af2

When we use the browser *headless mode* we must change the instruction `find_element_by_id` for `find_element_by_xpath` because the browser in headless mode sometimes does not find the element by **id** but by **XPath**

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the `--nogpu` argument to your chromeOptions. I've had to use that before to get headless working properly.

```
selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[--headless,--nogpu]" C:\path\to\file\prueba2.side
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late, but ...

For me it works if I specify the browserName like this:

```
selenium-side-runner -c "broswserName=chrome goog:chromeOptions.args=[-headless]" C:\path\to\file\prueba2.side
```

Normally you do not have to say that you use chrome, because it is the default, but the moment I started using the "-c" flag, I had to specify the name.